# No matching function for call in library

Tags: c++

I have a class with the public function in a dynamic library:

```
void setActiveAnimation(std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation> anim);
```

and when I attempt to call it like so:

```
    MaJR::Actor actor;
    actor.setActiveAnimation(idleAnimation);
```

I get the following:

```
/home/mike/NixCraft/main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
/home/mike/NixCraft/main.cpp|12|error: no matching function for call to 'MaJR::Actor::setActiveAnimation(MaJR::Animation&)'|
/home/mike/NixCraft/main.cpp|12|note: candidate is:|
/usr/include/MaJR/Actor.hpp|16|note: void MaJR::Actor::setActiveAnimation(std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation>)|
/usr/include/MaJR/Actor.hpp|16|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MaJR::Animation' to 'std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation>'|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error clearly states that you are trying to call the function with a reference to `MaJR::Animation` instead of a `std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation>`. Whenever you declare `idleAnimation` you should have instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation> idleAnimation( new MaJR::Animation() );
```

or better yet:

```
std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation> idleAnimation = std::make_shared<MaJR::Animation>();
```

Comment: So with smart pointers I also have to declare the original object as a pointer? That doesn't make sense to me. But whatever the C++ overlords decide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you have defined "idleAnimation", but I am guessing that it is not a pointer, but a reference to the actual object. setActiveAnimation() takes a pointer, so adjust your code accordingly.